# Dynamic Form Fields on Table using thymeleaf and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to create rows dynamically in a table using thymeleaf and spring boot.

I've looked at following urls but couldn't make it working for me.

http://forum.thymeleaf.org/I-have-problem-in-binding-the-list-of-objects-contained-inside-a-object-on-the-form-using-thymeleaf-td3525038.html#a3526497

http://stingh711.github.io/dynamic-form-with-springmvc-and-thymeleaf.html

when I click on the `addCourse` button, its not even going to StudentController.

please can someone help?

**Student.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-spring4-4.dtd">
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorator="layout">
<head>
<title>Students</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div layout:fragment="content">
    <form th:object="${student}" th:action="@{/student/create}" action="#" method="post">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                <div class="panel panel-success">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Add New Student</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{studentId}" class="form-control" placeholder="Student Id" />
                        <div style="clear: both; display: block; height: 10px;"></div> 
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" />
                        <div style="clear: both; display: block; height: 10px;"></div>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" />
                        <div style="clear: both; display: block; height: 10px;"></div>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{city}" class="form-control" placeholder="City" />
                        <div style="clear: both; display: block; height: 10px;"></div>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right"
                            value="Save">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- start of detail section -->
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                <div class="panel panel-success">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Student Courses</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="btn-success">
                                    <th>Course</th>
                                    <th>End Date</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr th:each="studentCourse, rowStat : *{studentCourses}">
                                <td></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{studentCourses[__${rowStat.index}__].courseId}" placeholder="Course" /></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{studentCourses[__${rowStat.index}__].endDate}"  placeholder="End Date"/>
                                    <span class="col-sm-1 row-delete-button">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" th:value="*{studentCourses[__${rowStat.index}__].studentCourseId}" name="removeStudentCourse">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash icon-white"></i>
                                        </button>
                                </span>

                                    </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="submit" name="addCourse">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus gs"></i> <b> Add</b>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                </div>

        </div>
        <!-- end of detail  -->
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**StudentController**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Student", params = {"addCourse"})
public String addCourse(Student student, BindingResult result) {
    System.out.println("add new course");

    student.getCourseList().add(new StudentCourse());
    return "Student";
}
```

**js.html (locatated @ templates/fragments)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-spring4-4.dtd">

<script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js}"></script>
```

**style.html (locatated @ templates/fragments)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-spring4-4.dtd">

<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
```

Comment: how does the submit button know what information to send and who to send it to?

Comment: Please post your full HTML. Where is the form tag? It should contain the action url `"/Student"` like you mentioned in your controller.

Comment: @Lucky, please see updated Student.html

Comment: @Muhammad Can you try `th:action="/Student"` ? Because your action URL and the URL in your controller should match. Or you should change in the controller like `"/student/create"`.

Comment: @Lucky, its going in the controller but now throwing error---java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at com.school.controller.StudentController.addCourse(StudentController.java:73) ~[classes/:na]
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]

Comment: line 73 is ---student.getCourseList().add(new StudentCourse());